# How convert byte [] to drawable?

Tags: android, byte, drawable

I have an array of bytes and I need to convert it into a Android Drawable.

How can I perform this conversion?

I have try this but doesn't works:

`fileData` is the `byte[]` array

```
Drawable image = null;
image =  new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(fileData, 0, fileData.length));
```

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work? Exception with stacktraces? Is nothing visible?

Answer (score 1):

used this code

```
byte[] imageByteArray = cursor.getBlob(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT11));

                if (imageByteArray != null) {
                    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            imageByteArray);
                    Bitmap company_logo = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream(imageStream);
                    img_logo.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                    img_logo.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(
                            getResources(), company_logo));
                }
```